# Slicing Power Spectral Density over frequency bands

Tags: matlab

I am using pwelch to get the Power Spectral Density of multiple signal vectors and then finding the average signal to noise ratios over 5 frequency bands.

I converted the power spectral densities to dB and am currently obtaining each band one by one:

```
P_signal1(band1)
P_signal1(band2)
P_signal1(band3)
```

...

```
P_signal2(band1)
P_signal2(band2)
```

and so on.

Is there any way to obtain this easily, maybe using arrays of the signals and the bands

```
signals = [P_signal1, P_signal2, P_signal3, P_signal4, P_signal5]
bands = [band1, band2, band3, band4, band5]
```

and obtain a matrix of  each combination?

Answer (score 0):

```
A = 1:100;
bands = [1:20;21:40;41:60;61:80;81:100];
A(bands)
```

Full documentation can be seen [here](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

The idea is indexing in Matlab is a lot different than in other languages, since Matlab uses matrices. When you index an array like `A(1)`, it will pick one element out, just like any other language. When you index it as `A([2,1;3,1])`, magic happens. Matlab will take out elements of `A` 4 times, each corresponding to one element in `[2,1;3,1]`. And then it arranges the 4 results in the same form of `[2,1;3,1]`. The output will be also a matrix.

---

EDIT: Using cell array

```
A = 1:100;
bands = {1:20;21:40;41:60;61:80;81:100};
cell2mat( cellfun(@(x) A(x), bands, 'UniformOutput', false) )
```

This works differently than above, but shares similar idea. Now `bands` is a cell array, each element containing an index range.

`cellfun` takes each of this range as `x`, and evaluate expression `A(x)` (which means access that part of `A`), and put the result into a new cell array, of which the size is same with `bands`, and the element position accords to the definition in `bands`.

`cell2mat` converts this output cell array into a plain numeric array.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: I used a cell array in order to differentiate each frequency band:    
    [P_signal1, F] = pwelch(...)
    bands = {find( F > 75 & F < 150); 
        find( F > 150 & F < 300);
        find( F > 300 & F < 600);
        find( F > 600 & F < 1200);
        find( F > 1200 & F < 2400);};
P_signal1(bands) doesn't work... is there any way to use a cell array?